# How to add email functionality into express route

Tags: express

I have a MEAN application that's working fine. Below is the Express back-end now for a route that creates a new user (the authentication credentials), and it's working well. At the place that's marked as such below (or in any other suitable place), I'd like to send an email message to the new user before (or after) the route completes and the browser re-directs:

What I have now:

1. Post to back-end
2. Validate and Sanitize
3. Save new user data
4. Redirect

What I want to achieve:

1. Post to back-end
2. Validate and Sanitize
3. Save new user data

   ---
4. SEND WELCOME AND/OR TWO-FACTOR AUTHENTICATION EMAIL

   ---
5. Redirect

Current back-end route to create new user (`users_controller.js`)

```
exports.user_create_post = [
    (req,res, next) => {
        next();
    },
    //VALIDATE
    body('mainEmail', 'Must be valid email.').isLength({min: 5}).trim(),

    //SANITIZE
    sanitizeBody('*').escape(),
 
    //POPULATE NEW DOCUMENT
    (req,res,next) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);

        var auth = new Auth(
            { 
                username: {"value": req.body.username},
                password: {"value": req.body.password},
                mainEmail: {"value": req.body.mainEmail}
            });
        var user = new UserObj(
            {authData: [auth] 
            }
        );
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
         //HANDLE ERRORS
            }
            else {
                user.save(function(err){
                    if (err) { return next(err);}
// HERE'S WHERE I WANT TO SEND A CONGRATULATIONS OR TWO-FACTOR AUTHENTICATION E-MAIL (before redirecting). >>
                    res.redirect("http://localhost:4200/welcome/");                    

                });
            }
        }
    ];
```

Here is the approach I'm trying to take to add the e-mail functionality:

```
            else {
                user.save(function(err){
                    if (err) { return next(err);}
// HERE'S WHERE I WANT TO SEND A CONGRATULATIONS OR TWO-FACTOR AUTHENTICATION E-MAIL (before redirecting). >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
                   app.mailer.send('email', {
                        to: 'fubar@fubar.com',
                        subject: 'Congrats'
                    }, function (err){
                        if (err) {
                            console.log(err);
                            res.send("There was an error sending the email");
                            return;
                        }
 
                    })
// >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
                    res.redirect("http://localhost:4200/welcome/");                    
. . .
```

At the top of `users_controller.js` I also add:

```
var mailer = require('express-mailer');
var app = require('../app');

mailer.extend(app, {
    from: 'joe_schmoe@hotmail.com',
    host: 'smtp.hotmail.com', // hostname
    secureConnection: true, // use SSL
    port: 465, // port for secure SMTP
    transportMethod: 'SMTP', // default is SMTP. Accepts anything that nodemailer accepts
    auth: {
      user: 'joe_schmoe@hotmail.com',
      pass: 'foobar'
    }
  });
```

Currently, the code as above is not compiling and I get an error:

```
ERROR:

 mailer.render = createRender(app.render.bind(app));
                                           ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined
    at Object.exports.extend (C:\Users\Cleese\dev\krush\krush-back-end\node_modules\express-mailer\lib\express-mailer.js:112:44) . . .
```

My questions are:

1. Is my approach to adding the email functionality generally valid, or am I way off base? If the approach is generally valid, how should I fix the code to make it work?
2. If my approach is not valid, what general approach should I take to slot the email functionality into the middleware stack?

Comment: @crowdplesar, if you want to retain your current implementation, you can do like. No need to configure email in users controller. Just use that config in app.js. And then simple use app instance to send email.

Comment: But better way is that use a separate module for sending mail using Nodemailer or something else & then use that module in your respective file to send emails

Comment: Have a look on implementaion for your reference: https://github.com/techyaura/techx1.0/blob/master/src/utils/email.util.js.

Comment: Thank you, @techyaura. That's very interesting, and I'm studying that. I have a basic Javascript question . . .  In your code, you have the following `transporter() {
    return Nodemailer.createTransport(
      this.constructor.smtpConfigOptions(),
    );
  }' 
What does the line: `this.constructor.smtpConfigOptions()` mean? I'm not familiar with that syntax. Why `this.constructor.smtpConfigOptions`? Why isn't it just `this.smtpConfigOptions()`? Thank you, and sorry in advance for such a basic question!

Comment: smtpConfigOptions is a static method, that's why I have used.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the difference between `this.constructor.smtpConfigOptions()` and `this.smtpConfigOptions()`? (Why do you need to add the `constructor` into that expression? What role does the constructor play?) Thank you!